# How to Change blue background selection color from image using css

Tags: html, css

**Can any one help me how to remove blue color from image on selection
you can see screenshot from here...**

[image]

Comment: Seriously? You create a jsfiddle, which contains one screenshot?!

Comment: when i select ctrl + a all images which are in img tag are getting blue that i want to remove i can't attach image because of credit that's why i had put image in jsfeiddle sorry friends but i was confuse how to upload image :)

Comment: Aren't those images wrapped inside an anchor or something? Maybe you need to remove the selection background of those elements too/instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) property (though pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> will still cause the blue selection background to appear as @WebDesignerRDj pointed out):

```
img {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rU2y4/2/

Comment: But when i select whole items in page by Ctrl + A image getting blue color still by this solution... 

 [JSFeed](http://jsfiddle.net/rU2y4/1/)

Comment: @WebDesignerRDj: Ah I didn't know that - I think you may have to use JS

Comment: any idea which js may i use ??

Comment: But Adrift's answer is correct, this is how to do this with CSS.. Although I don't know why you're trying to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
::selection {
color: #e2e2e2;
background-color: #999;
}
```

**Note**: This only changes the font properites. Not the images.
However if you want to remove some background from image its Impossible with CSS. CSS is meant to edit the HTML style not the images. For that use Adobe Photoshop!
I am seriously not able to understand, why do you want to change the background of the image.
Ok there can be a solution. You create an image with transparent background! And change its background. A little more elaboration please.

**Edit:** You can use this for image background. But the div background will be changed. Use

```
background-color: none;
```

or

```
background-color: transparent;
```

This will not select the image. Not change the background to blue!

Comment: acctuly when i Ctrl + A in my browser images are getting blue color selection that's i want to remove via css or any javascript or jquery may this one help you ....

Comment: Yes, when you use this all the selections will be changed. You can change the selection color. Its background. The blue color will be changed if you use this method and set the background-color property to transparent or none!

Comment: i had use this property but it still doesn't work

::-moz-selection{background:transparent; color:inherit;}
::selection{background:transparent; color:inherit;}
::-webkit-selection{background:transparent; color:inherit;}

Comment: Try to use background-color: transparent.